# c# solution for screenscraping into a datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, excel, vba

i have an excel macro that i am converting to c#. currently i am manually going to an already opened IE window, copying everything from it (html table) and pasting into excel worksheet. then i am manipulating the data. this works very well because pasting an html table into excel works fine!

i am trying to do the same thing in c# WITHOUT excel. i need to:

1. get data from IE window
2. read it into a datatable (in a similar way that if i were copying and pasting html table into excel sheet)

do you know if this is easily possible to do?

the TITLE of the IE window will be the same all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could skip the IE window and just use one of the web classes (WebClient, HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse) to load up a object version of the page.  That would give you access to all the HTML on a page.  Then you could parse the HTML and pull out whatever information you needed.  Once you have the information it's pretty easy to do whatever you want with it.

Try doing a search on [HTML parsing](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=HTML+parsing+c%23&aq=f&aqi=g-v4g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=83f87efc6f926f13) or [HTML Parser](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=HTML+parser+c%23&aq=f&aqi=g2g-v2g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=83f87efc6f926f13) and you should get some nice information on that topic.

**EDIT**

As another option, if you really don't want to do parsing.  You could always setup a form with a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) Control and then use it to load the page.  The WebBrowser control has a [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property that gives you access to a lot of the information on a page.

Comment: @tony thank you very much but i am trying to specifically get away from parsing html

Comment: May I inquire as to why you want to get away from parsing html?

Comment: @herrow: It's actually pretty easy.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Look at my edit for another option if you are really not comfortable with HTML parsing. It might be useful.